# Remove petstore spec when starting swagger editor

Tags: swagger-editor

I am using Swagger Editor locally in my machine.

When I start the Swagger Editor, it shows the spec for petstore by default at startup.

I want to remove that and show a blank editor. Is there a way to do that at startup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple workaround is to run the editor with the `?url=` parameter where the URL points to an empty page (no HTTP response body), such as http://httpbin.org/status/200.

http://editor.swagger.io/?url=http://httpbin.org/status/200

This will open a blank editor.

Alternatively, you can modify the editor's source code and build your own version. You will need Node.js 6.x and npm 3.x (as of time of this writing).

The default editor contents seems to be set here:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/blob/master/src/plugins/local-storage/index.js#L29

1. In `src\plugins\local-storage\index.js`, replace

   ```js
   import PetstoreYaml from "./petstore"
   ```

   with

   ```js
   const PetstoreYaml = ""
   ```
2. Rebuild the editor:

   ```
   npm run build
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Insert **url** property into [swagger-editor's index.html](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/blob/efe0d8c2/index.html#L54) like [swagger-ui's it](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/b9b4ab20/dist/index.html#L43).

### detail

[Open custom yaml spec in swagger editor on startup · Issue #1727 · swagger-api/swagger-editor](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/1727)

> You can use Swagger-UI's config options to load in your own definiton: there's url for fetching a remote document, and spec for passing in a JavaScript object directly. Swagger-Editor passes these options directly to its underlying Swagger-UI instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following js code to remove the default content in swagger editor.

```
 editor = SwaggerEditorBundle({
        dom_id: "#swagger-editor",
        layout: "StandaloneLayout",
        presets: [SwaggerEditorStandalonePreset]
      });
      window.editor = editor;
      // The line to remove the content in swagger editor
      editor.specActions.updateSpec(' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using docker image (docker pull swaggerapi/swagger-editor) to run locally the swagger editor, then provide your own local json or yaml file as below:

```
$ ls
teapi-openapi.yaml
$sudo docker run -d -p 9800:8080 -v $(pwd):/tmp -e SWAGGER_FILE=/tmp/teapi-openapi.yaml swaggerapi/swagger-editor
```

To access:

`http://<IP>:9800/`

where, ip is machine IP where swagger editor image is running, Replace 9800 with any port on which you want to access

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the next release v1.4.1, the following property will be added to disable the swagger-ui default petstore url:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
```

Copied from
https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/714#issuecomment-640215759

Comment: This does not work. Using Spring boot / springdoc v1.5.9.

Comment: The question is about [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/), not Swagger UI.

Answer (score 0):

These two properties worked for me:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/v1/api-docs  (<-- your API docs URL)
```